# problems installing MiKTeX 2.9 on windows 10 (64 bit)

Tags: miktex, installing, windows, distributions

I am trying for a couple of days now to install MiKTeX 2.9 but every time i'm starting to download the files on my laptop (currently running on win 10) it tell me :
the operation could not be completed because of the following file failed verification :
 and the file name changes almost every time

could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe a problem with your firewall?

Comment: i don't think so because i can download almost all the files

Comment: Do you have a `setup(datetime).log`?

Comment: my next question would be 'what is it using to verify'. there are some ISPs that will 'shadow-replace' internet requests with some login page – ask for (say) `article.cls` and you receive a hunk of HTML saying you're not logged in named `article.cls`. Obviously, the real `article.cls` is not a hunk of HTML, so file verification would fail. … Does your internet work otherwise? Can you access CTAN mirrors with your browser?

Comment: Idid not see any 
setup(datetime).log or any request to log into any pages

Comment: @SeanAllred I think i can because my internet connection goes threw a basic home rooter in france

Comment: @warhawkgre: The setup.log I mention has nothing  to see with a login. It is the installation report, that describes what happened during the installation, whether it failed or not.

Comment: so yes a dis have a setup log but in the end I stop trying with miktex ans i installed texlive and it works now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op installed other tex distribution.  The issue therefore can not be checked any longer ...